# Traducción de "excise" en referencia a user interface

Tags: traducción, identificación-de-término

En [esta respuesta](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/141851/115107) de UXSE, *excise* hace referencia al exceso de elementos en un interface de usuario, ya sean gráficos (visual excise) o de interactividad (excise task).

Todas las opciones que *Google Translate* da acerca de *excise* son "*impuestos especiales*" o algo en referencia a TAX que no tiene nada que ver en el contexto. No puedo encontrar una traducción real, a lo más próximo que he llegado es "imposición visual" o "tarea impuesta", pero creo que no es lo adecuado.

Alguna idea?

Comment: excise a tumor=cut it out. Don't confuse excise tax with the verb to excise.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the response on UXSE I think it is clear that the original author was referring to those things as something which puts extra work on the user and so are a form of tax. He was using it figuratively. I would translate it as *impuesto* without *especial* as that is only really relevant when it refers to actual *excise duties* levied by the state.

Comment: I think there is no Spanish analogy of TAX (impuesto) applied to a literal imposition, maybe I'm wrong. The closest thing I can think of is still "imposición". "Impuesto visual" sounds like a monetary tribute.

Answer (score 1):

El término inglés me resulta nuevo, pero el concepto no. Yo siempre he oído y me he referido a algunos interfaces de usuario como "recargados" o "sobrecargados", tanto respecto al aspecto visual como al del número de operaciones requeridas para obtener un resultado (ahora mismo estoy pensando en el Word de Microsoft...)

Se puede comprobar que expresiones como "[sobrecarga visual](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22sobrecarga%20visual%22%20interfaz)" o "[carga visual](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22carga%20visual%22%20interfaz)" son habituales en diseño de interfaces.

Comment: La parte visual la tengo clara, "ruido" es el término utilizado habitualmente. El problema es con la sobrecarga de acciones *inútiles*. No conozco la palabra *excise* y las traducciones que encuentro en internet no son lo suficientemente claras. De momento "tarea impuesta" es la que mejor se adapta, pero sigo teniendo mis dudas.

Comment: "Inútiles" no describe el concepto del todo. Son tareas requeridas por las herramientas, no por el objetivo, como comentan [aquí](https://www.zeepedia.com/read.php?behavior_form_eliminating_excise_navigation_and_inflection_human_computer_interaction&b=11&c=28).

Comment: De hecho, me gusta lo de "tareas impuestas" (por la herramienta) porque, igual que el original, incluye los conceptos de impuesto y tarea.

Comment: A todo esto... estoy seguro de que el que acuñó el término lo hizo para aprovechar el juego de palabras entre "excise tax" y "excise task".

Comment: Muy interesante el artículo de Zeepedia, lo tendré que desmenuzar punto por punto.  Aunque me aleja de que el concepto "excise" sea el más adecuado para mi pregunta en UXSE puesto que lo interpreta como una tarea impuesta pero necesaria para llegar a un objetivo. La imagen ejemplo de la pregunta es una tarea innecesaria. Hay una palabra en español que desconocía que es [exacción](https://dle.rae.es/exacci%C3%B3n) y se acerca bastante al concepto.